# Error while getting value from an array

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

I have an array I call with an api connection.

```
["data"]=>
  object(stdClass)#212 (3) {
    ["status_code"]=>
    int(200)
    ["data"]=>
    object(stdClass)#211 (3) {
      ["days"]=>
      int(30)
      ["total_clicks"]=>
      int(6)
      ["clicks"]=>
      array(30) {
        [0]=>
        object(stdClass)#215 (2) {
          ["clicks"]=>
          int(0)
          ["day_start"]=>
          int(1466395200)
        }
        [1]=>
        object(stdClass)#216 (2) {
          ["clicks"]=>
          int(0)
          ["day_start"]=>
          int(1466308800)
        }
```

I try to get the first

```
["data"]=>
  object(stdClass)#212 (3) {
    ["status_code"]=>
    int(200)
    ["data"]=>
    object(stdClass)#211 (3) {
      ["days"]=>
      int(30)
      ["total_clicks"]=>
      int(6)
      ["clicks"]=>
      array(30) {
        [0]=>
        object(stdClass)#215 (2) {
          ["clicks"]=>
          int(0)
```

I try to do so with the following function (the array itself is stored in the "$data" variable):

```
function currentClicks($data)
        {
            $path = $data->data->data->clicks;
            foreach ($path as $key => $item) {
                $array[] = [$item->clicks[0]];
            }
            return json_encode($array);
        }
```

And I echo it in a  tag: `<h1><?php echo currentClicks($data); ?></h1>`
The problem is that instead of displaying the value (which is the number 0) I get an error in console displaying

```
[[null],[null],[null],[null],[null],[null],[null],[null],[null],[null],[null],[null],[null],[null],[null],[null],[null],[null],[null],[null],[null],[null],[null],[null],[null],[null],[null],[null],[null],[null]]
```

I just need the number (integer) from the first record [0]. In this case the number is 0.But I don't know how to fetch it.

```
       [0]=>
        object(stdClass)#215 (2) {
          ["clicks"]=>
          int(0)
```

Comment: `$item->clicks` isn't an array.

Comment: `$array[] = $item->clicks;` Or if your really want an array of single element arrays: `$array[] = [$item->clicks];`

Comment: I only need [0]=>
        object(stdClass)#215 (2) {
          ["clicks"]=>
          int(0)

Comment: $array[] = $item->clicks;

Comment: As you can see there are multiple record of 'clicks' everyday a new record is inserted. I only require the first one [0]...

Comment: If you only want 1 result, why are your ittersating through all of them? `return $data->data->data->clicks[0]->clicks` The fact you are using the same property name (`clicks`, `data`) at different levels is certainly confusing matters

Comment: I know but it is not up to me, thank you it solved the problem.